# Javascript array adding extra space while representation

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]

Question is : When i am doing console.log(a) then extra space is added and same is flowed to the backend and that gets broken at due to extra space added to each element after 1st.
How to remove this and why this is a problem?

Comment: There can't be an "extra space" because the array only contain numbers and not strings.

Comment: Where is the extra space?

Comment: where is extra space ?

Comment: Where is your code ? What should be the expected output ?

Comment: The extra space you see is just the string representation of the array, there is no actual extra space.

Comment: I can see same space at my java server too, when i am debugging it.

Answer (score 2):

The extra space you notice when you are using your `console.log()` is added by the browser for readability purpose only.

Example, open Chrome console and type

`[10,20]`

A second line will show up with your array:

`[10, 20]`

The extra space before `20` is only for readability and added in the console.

If you serialize the array you will notice no space is there:

`JSON.stringify([10,20]);`

Answer (score 0):

There must be some other problem. Number can't be an "extra space" and your array contains only numbers. `Console.log(a)` shows it just for better visualizations. It did not actual space in number.